# Get parameter names at runtime with Java sbt

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

Is there no equivalent **compiler option** (like Maven's `-parameters` configuration) to get the **parameter name** at runtime?

The parameter will be named `arg0`, `arg1`, etc, at runtime.

I've tried setting:

```xml
scalacOptions += "-parameters"
```

By parameter name, I mean

```java
public void test(String foo) {}
```

`foo` is the name of the first parameter.

Comment: define "parameter name"

Comment: What do you mean by parameter name? Any kind of program args will be passed into `String[] args` which is within the `static void main()` method.

Comment: `public void test(String foo) {}` the name of the first parameter is `foo`

Comment: I need this for https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr